# JAVA JPA persistence.xml - how to test connection validity before use in my application

Tags: jpa, jdbc, timeout, persistence

I use Google Guice Persist ( JPA ) to operate the data. My web application is on the Jetty server. Following is my persistence.xml：

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="MyJpaUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>my.api.repository.entity.Foo</class>
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/testing?characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test_account" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test_pwd" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="format_sql" value="false"/>

            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="30" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I got the following error when my application was idle：

> [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 49,492,938 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 49,492,938 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 49,492,938 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 49,492,938 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

How can i configure the persistence.xml to avoid this problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: not familiar with c3p0, but in other pools you have to specify a "testQuery" that gets run periodically to check if the connection is still alive.

Comment: Hi Thilo, thanks for your reply. I add the "testQuery" but it still not work. I have updated my configuration above.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this problem. The reason of this problem is unclosed entity manager. Please create a new entity manager whenever you do something on db and after that close the entity manager.